# How to talk to a debugger,, or change exception message?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, exception, ollydbg

I know how to handle exceptions
using 
Try .. catch kind what i actually do

```
push handler
push fs:[0]
.....
```

Once an exception occurs the debugger log file would throw 
 Message=Access violation when writing to [00000001]

How do i throw another message to the debugger like "Function Calculate Started"
using asm32 or Visual C++

so how can i talk to the debugger?

Comment: On what system with what compiler? Debugging tends to be fairly specific to both.

Comment: Use OutputDebugString() in your code.  This is pretty unnecessary in general, you could just look at the stack trace.

Comment: Windows, compiler would be WinAsm MASM32 or Visual C++

Comment: Are you tied to using ollydbg?  I'm not familiar with it, but debuggers for Windows code should be able to cope with all manner of debug exceptions (including OutputDebugString).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are really after WinAPI's [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), olly will log this (so will any other debugger watching the global debug mutex), so will sysinternals dbgview.

Comment: unpatched Ollydbg will send this for OutputDebugString(pString) and i get in ollydbg log file exception: 40010006

Comment: i used OutputDebugString("test") and the debugger log showed me, Exception: 40010006 not the text itself ...

however windbg works just fine
 why is that?

Comment: @Ben: you are doing something wrong then, it works fine here for me. Make sure you are using the correct version for your character set (in your case `OutputDebugStringA`)

Comment: my own bad guys. some plugin messed it up thanks to you all! :)

Comment: By the way if anyone want's to know,

Stealth 64 plugin

Protect Against > OutputDebugString 

so obvious once you figure out it's a plugin

Comment: @Ben: use ollyadvanced to fix the `OutputDebugString` exploit rather, it still leaves the logging functional

Answer (score 0):

An old trick at least in x86 was to issue an "int 3". Not sure if this would still work on mainstream operating systems.

Comment: This still works for x86 and x64 assembly code written to run on Windows.  In C/C++, however, it's preferable to use a compiler intrinsic like __debugbreak() or a similar wrapping function from the Windows APIs.

Comment: i don't need to pause the application i need to send message to ollydbg log once it enters a specific function

Comment: You just stopped the process (or crashed it with no debugger present), how are you going to send a message?

Comment: What you mean by sending a message? There is no such concept.